# Como puedo agrupar un JSON y mostrar sus datos en diferentes tablas?

Tags: javascript, html, json

lo que pasa es que quiero mostrar la información de este JSON el cual lo cargo de msqyl y se actualiza cada vez que se introducen datos, lo que quiero es que se puedan agrupar por ciudad esos datos y mostrarlos en diferentes tablas por la agrupacion en ciudad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    DATA FROM JSON

var data = [
        {
             Nombre: 'Fulano Detal',
             Descripcion: 'Un string explicando a qué se dedica',
             Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 1'
        },
        {
            Nombre: 'Otro Fulano',
            Descripcion: 'String diferente que tambien describe su trabajo',
            Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 1'
        },
        {
            Nombre: 'Tercer Fulano',
            Descripcion: 'Su trabajo en donde sea que este',
            Ciudad: 'CIUDAD 2'
        }
    ]   



<script>
      let url = 'http://localhost:4000/apis/xd';
      fetch(url)
            .then( response => response.json() )
            .then( data => mostrarData(data) )
            .catch( error => console.log(error) )

    const mostrarData = (data) => {
    const unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.Ciudad))]; //ciudades (no se repiten)
    for (var j = 0; j < unique.length; j++) {
      var tempArray = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {      
        if(data[i].Ciudad == unique[j]) {
          tempArray.push(data[i]);
        }
      }

         let title = ""
         let head = ""
         let body = ""

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {     
               body+=`<tr id="${data[i].Ciudad}"><td>${data[i].Nombre}</td> 
               <td>${data[i].Descripcion}</td><tr><tbody>`

                 
                   document.getElementById("tabla").innerHTML = body;

            }
       


 console.log(tempArray);      //aqui lo agregas a cada tabla. 


    }
    }
   </script>
```

E estado tratando de mostrar los datos asi pero no e podido hacerlo no se como puedo hacer que se muestre los datos de una ciudad en una tabla por que se crea una tabla por dato

Comment: Qué has intentado? Copia y pega el código donde intentas hacer la agrupación. Tal vez estás muy cerca de la solución y sólo necesitas un ajuste de parte nuestra.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.Ciudad))]; //ciudades (no se repiten)
    for (var j = 0; j < unique.length; j++) {
      var tempArray = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {      
        if(data[i].Ciudad == unique[j]) {
          tempArray.push(data[i]);
        }
      }
      console.log(tempArray); //aqui lo agregas a cada tabla. 
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero deberias leerte [answer] para seguir las directrices marcadas en este sitio para elaborar buenas respuestas. Actualmente [las respuestas con solo código son votadas negativamente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2882#2882).  Aparte de eso, no deberiamos contestar tareas que no muestran ningún esfuerzo por parte del OP, tal como se indica en [answer] en la frase **son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real.** del apartado **Contesta preguntas bien formadas**

Comment: @masterguru lo siento vengo de la version ingles y no tienen problemas con las respuestas como la mia. Ejem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491101/javascript-create-array-from-for-loop

Comment: Son respuestas de hace 3 años como muy pronto... quizas las normas han cambiado desde entonces, yo llevo aqui 5 meses y es lo que he aprendido y me han ido orientando desde que he llegado.  No es nada personal, esta claro, no pretendo ofender, tan solo te digo lo que ha mi me han enseñado aqui.

Comment: @Frnk edite la pregunta gracias por tu aporte

Comment: @SPENTCRAFT si te sirvio la respuesta, porfavor no olvides marcarla como util.